# How to efficiently and "pythonically" remove "old" rows from pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a huge `pandas.DataFrame` with a `CreationDateTime` column. This column contains datetimes as strings and its values indicate the "age" of their respective row.

```
PRID             CreationDate  
0     2017-11-29 14:51:39.300   
1     2017-11-29 15:52:08.963  
2     2017-11-29 16:52:40.710  
3     2017-11-29 17:53:16.207  
4     2017-11-29 18:53:46.557
```

How can I efficiently remove the rows from the oldest day in the set?

What I managed to do so far was this:

```py
d = pd.read_csv(base_dataset, delimiter=delimiter)
d['CreationDay'] = pd.to_datetime(d['CreationDateTime']).dt.date
g = d.groupby('CreationDay', sort=True)
g = iter(g)
_ = next(g)  # ignore first day.
g = list(g)
d = pd.concat(d for day, d in g)  # concat all others.
```

Still, it doesn't seem very efficient and I was looking for something more pythonic, like `d.groupby('CreationDay', sort=True).skip(1).flat()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the column to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime`:

```
v = pd.to_datetime(df.CreationDate).dt.date
```

Next, find the minimum date and compare to get a mask. Use the mask to filter `df`.

```
df[v.gt(v.min())]
```

This removes all rows whose date is the same as the minimum date found.